# How to return the values from a row where a value occurs for the first time among the rows available?

Tags: plugins, query, hooks

I have a database table in WordPress as in the following example:

```
ID | Allocation_number | Treatment | Used 
1 | 1 | A | 0
2 | 2 | B | 0
3 | 3 | B | 0
4 | 4 | A | 0
```

And the rows continues upto X times. The "Allocation_number" starts from 1 and increases by +1. "Used" column has "0" or "1", 0 indicating NOT USED YET, 1 = USED ALREADY. This column Used maybe is not essential - however, I thought by using this logic we might indicate the first available treatment (not used yet). The treatment options are strings (here A or B chosen at random)

When a user FETCHES the first AVAILABLE Treatment in the QUEUE, the USED column's value is UPDATED and 0 is replaced by 1.
When the first user will get the first treatment A, the table should look:

```
ID | Allocation_number | Treatment | Used
1 | 1 | A | 1
2 | 2 | B | 0
3 | 3 | B | 0
4 | 4 | A | 0
```

Q: How could I achieve a scenario where the NEXT visitor who triggers a button will get the FOLLOWING AVAILABLE treatment (in this case B) allocated for him / her. The next one will get the next available, that is B.

In other words the SQL Query must find the VALUE of the column **Treatment** in the row where **Used** column value has the **first occurrence** of the value 0 - that is the first yet UNUSED treatment?

Could anybody help me to get the correct SQL query or hook for this? Or does any body have a similar plugin for WordPress to achieve this?

Comment: Getting the correct row from the database is more of an SQL question, not a WordPress one.

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is to use MySQL's "ORDER BY" feature:

```
SELECT Treatment FROM my_table WHERE Used=0 ORDER BY Allocation_number ASC LIMIT 1
```

So you look for all rows where Used=0, order (sort) them by Allocation_number in ascending order, and then pick the first row that matches. ("LIMIT 1")

I'll let you plug this into [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) as an exercise... ;)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I did my homework and wrote my first plugin to accomplish this. I have added a short code to call this function.
I could get the data from the database using your suggestion and it works.

This is my final code:

```
        function return_treatment_type(){
        global $wpdb;
        $tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'random';  // Ensures  that your table name matches the prefix in config.wp
        $where = ['random_ID' => $_POST[hidden]];
        $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
        $user->roles[0];
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $url = "http://some.domain";
        $myData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT random_ID, treat_type, user_id, allocationused_date, random_owner, randomnumero_used, random_number, comment, created, updated FROM `$tableName` WHERE randomnumero_used=0 ORDER BY random_number ASC LIMIT 1");

        foreach ( $myData as $myNData )
        {
          echo "<form action='#'  method=post>";
          echo "<input type=datetime       name=allocationused_date  value=" . $myNData->allocationused_date . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=bigint(60)     name=user_id    value=" . $current_user->user_login . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=varchar(191)   name=random_owner  value=" . $myNData->random_owner . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=longtext       name=treat_type   value=" . $myNData->treat_type . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=tinyint(2)     name=randomnumero_used  value=" . $myNData->randomnumero_used . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=int(10)        name=random_number  value=" . $myNData->random_number . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=longtext       name=comment  value=" . $myNData->comment . "><br>";
          echo "<input type=bigint(20)     name=random_ID   value=" . $myNData->random_ID . ">";
          echo "<input type=hidden         name=hidden   value=" . $myNData->random_ID . ">";
          echo "<input type=submit         name=update       value=update" . ">";
          echo "</form>";
        }

        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
          foreach (['allocationused_date', 'user_id', 'random_owner', 'random_number', 'treat_type', 'randomnumero_used', 'comment', 'created', 'updated', 'random_ID',] as $field) {
          $data[$field] = $_POST[$field];
          }
    if( $wpdb->update($tableName, $data, $where) === FALSE)
        echo "Failed";
    else
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
        }       
        }       
add_shortcode('random', 'return_treatment_type');
```